# Full screen using flash builder Actionscript Mobile project

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, flash-builder, fullscreen

1. I create a very simple **Action-script Mobile project** using Flash builder 4.6
   and I select both automatically reorient  and **full-screen** mode
2. I'm using an external SWC file to import some graphics

This is the result when testing my application on an android device:
[image]

The problem : **My application is not full-screen why?**. As you can see in the image, I have a big white area and my application is in the upper-left corner and too small.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This one should help you: [LINK](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow/quick-guide-to-creating-and-using-swcs/)

Comment: but the problem still the same

Comment: Its is always better to put more than just a link for an answer. I have the same problem, and your link didn't help at all.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I found a link that could help, 
[How to set an AS3 application size according to the screen size (for mobile devices)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824452/how-to-set-an-as3-application-size-according-to-the-screen-size-for-mobile-devi)

I added `stage.scaleMode = "noScale";` inside the main function of the main `AS` file which help fix the problem.